# How and when Promise `.then`, `.catch` and `.finally` land in EventLoop micro-tasks queue?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Are `.then`, `.catch` and `.finally` land in JS Event Loop immediately after being registered (when appropriate code is interpreted by JS runtime) or somehow differently?

The less theoretical face of this question is the following :

I have the following code ( Link to [JSBin (online JS execution environment)](https://jsbin.com/poqoguqewo/4/edit?js,console) )

```js
l = console.log

const g = (title) => {
    return (a) => {
      l(title + a)
      return a+1;
    }
};

const gA = g("A ")
const gB = g("B ")

const throwError = (title) => {
    return (a) => {
      l(title + a)
      throw new Error("Error from promise " + title + a)
    }
}; 

promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1)
})

l("Started application")

promise
  .then(gA)
  .then(gA)
  .then(throwError("A "))
  .catch(err => {
    l(err.message);
  })


promise
  .then(throwError("B "))
  .then(gB)
  .then(gB)
  .catch(err => {
    l(err.message);
  })

l("Finish main function")
```

that resolves to the following output in the console

```
"Started application"
"Finish main function"
"A 1"
"B 1"
"A 2"
"A 3"
"Error from promise A 3"
"Error from promise B 1"
```

If promise callbacks were to be executed in the order they were registered, I would expect `"Error from promise B 1"` to be higher in this output. But they appear in the end. **Why is this happening?**

Comment: "*I would expect "Error from promise B 1" to be higher in this output.*" - why is that? The `.catch(err => {
    l(err.message);
  })` is registered *last* after all. (True, it could happen at any point after the "B 1" output, but there's no reason to expect a specific ordering in relation to the other "A 2" etc callbacks. It would happen before them if `gA` returned a promise for a timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do `.then`, `.catch` and `.finally` land in JS Event Loop immediately after being registered or somehow differently?

Those promise methods themselves never land in the queue. The task queue contains *promise reactions*, which basically say "run callbacks X/Y on the result of promise Z". (And they're always pairs of `then` callbacks, as that's what `catch` and `finally` use internally).

These promise reactions are scheduled as soon as the promise is settled, or scheduled immediately during the `then` call when promise already was settled.

> If promise callbacks were to be executed in the order they were registered

They are. But this holds only *per promise*. The only promise in your code that you are attaching multiple callbacks to is `promise`, and `gA` *does* run earlier than `throwError("B ")`. There are no guarantees for callbacks that are attached to different promises, as those promises would settle at different times anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `resolve()` a promise fullfillment / rejection gets queued into the promise microtask queue. Then when the task gets run, all respective `.then`s / `.catch`s attached to *that promise* get run in order of attachment.

```
 promise.then(first);
 promise.then(second);
```

Now `.then` returns itself a Promise, whose resolve gets called when the callback gets executed. Therefore a `.then` attached to a Promise returned by `.then` gets executed at least one microtask later:

```
 const secondPromise = firstPromise.then(first);
 // one microtick after first run, secondPromise fullfills, and therefore attached .thens get run
 secondPromise.then(second);
```

Comment: "*gets executed one microtask later*" - if there were no other queued microtasks, and iff the first callback did not return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shares, let's say promise A to below:

```
promise
  .then(gA)
  .then(gA)
  .then(throwError("A "))
  .catch(err => {
    l(err.message);
  })
```

and promise B to below:

```
promise
  .then(throwError("B "))
  .then(gB)
  .then(gB)
  .catch(err => {
    l(err.message);
  })
```

Then as we know asynchronous behavior of promises, console.log will always finish execution before hence it prints at very first but meanwhile promise A & B both have started already but will start printing after console.logs.

According to order i.e promise A first and promise B second, both falls on their first .then i.e. promise A -> .then(1st) is executed then promise b -> .then(1st) hence it prints

```
"A 1" //no exception called here hence will start execution of next .then
"B 1" //prints from throw called here and remains alive with 1 hence will never allow any of next .then() to execute.
"A 2" // 2nd .then executed
"A 3" // 3rd .then executed followed by throw and again remains alive with 3
```

If error occurs then will enters catch, and then "throw" will always finish execution in the end, so as per the order promise A is before promise B, below is shown

```
"Error from promise A 3" // 3 because of last successful increment
"Error from promise B 1" // 1 because of throw did not allow increment
```

So here is the order I believe, if .then() return cascading promises then it depends on time of a response resolve.